# Receiving and using multiple inputs in classes

Tags: class, python-2.7, input

I'm trying to write a class program for complex mathematics with imaginary numbers. (Basically, doing math with a +bi.) The current problem I'm having is two-fold. First, I can't come up with a way to take and use two separate inputs from the user. And the second is using the **init** function with two different sets of numbers at the same time. Here's the basics of what I've got:

```
class Complex(object):

    def __init__(self, other, a = 0, b = 0):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "c1 is (" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)\n"

    def __add__(self, other):
        noni = self._a + self._c
        yi = self._b + self._d
        if noni == 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " + (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(yi) + "i."
        elif noni != 0 and yo == 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " + (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(noni) + "."
        elif noni != 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " + (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(noni) + " , " + str(yi) + "i."
        else:
            return "0"


    def __sub__(self):
        noni = self._a - self._c
        yi = self._b - self._d
        if noni == 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " - (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = (" \
                   + str(yi) + "i)"
        elif noni != 0 and yo == 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " - (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = (" \
                   + str(noni) + ")"
        elif noni != 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " - (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = (" \
                   + str(noni) + " , " + str(yi) + "i)"
        else:
            return "0"


    def __mul__(self):
        noni = self._a * self._c
        yi = self._b * self._d
        if noni == 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " * (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(yi) + "i)"
        elif noni != 0 and yo == 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " * (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(noni) + ")"
        elif noni != 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " * (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(noni) + " , " + str(yi) + "i)"
        else:
            return "0"


    def __div__(self):
        noni = self._a / self._c
        yi = self._b / self._d
        if noni == 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " / (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(yi) + "i)"
        elif noni != 0 and yo == 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " / (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(noni) + ")"
        elif noni != 0 and yi != 0:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)" \
                   + " / (" + str(self._c) + " , " + str(self._d) + "i) = " \
                   + str(noni) + " , " + str(yi) + "i)"
        else:
            return "0"

def main():
    c1 = (raw_input("Enter the first complex number: "))
    c1.split()
    c1 = Complex(c1)
    c2 = (raw_input("Enter the first complex number: "))
    c2.split()
    c2 = Complex(c1)
    print c1
    print c2
    print c1 + c2
    print c1 - c2
    print c1 * c2
    print c1 / c2

main()
```

Here's a sample of the intended results.

Enter the first complex number: 2.5, 4.5

Enter the second complex number: -2.5, 11.2

c1 is (2.5 , 4.5i)

c2 is (-2.5 , 11.2i)

(2.5 , 4.5i)  +  (-2.5 , 11.2i)  =  15.7i

(2.5 , 4.5i)  -  (-2.5 , 11.2i)  =  (5.0 , -6.7i)

(2.5 , 4.5i)  *  (-2.5 , 11.2i)  =  (-56.65 , 16.75i)

(2.5 , 4.5i)  /  (-2.5 , 11.2i)  =  (0.335257043056 , -0.298048447111i)

I'll take any help that's given, but the biggest ones are the input and **init**.

Answer (score 0):

First, just in case you are not aware of that, Python has complex numbers built in (e.g. `1 + 2j`). As for your code:

1) Why do you have `other` in `__init__`? It does not seem to serve any purpose there.

2) Why do you have duplicated printing code in all of the operations instead of using `__str__` (to say nothing about why a sum of two complex numbers returns a string...)?

3) `split()` method of the string returns its result, it does not change the variable in place.

4) If you want to pass a sequence as arguments for a function, use splicing operator `*` (if I understood your problem correctly). Alternatively, you can just take the first and second element of what `split` returns and pass them to your `__init__`.

5) What are `self._c` and `self._d` attributes you use? Shouldn't these be `other._a` and `other._b`?

6) Your `__mul__` and `__div__` implementation is incorrect, complex numbers do not work this way.

With all this in mind, the modified program would look like (leaving the weird `str`-returning behavior intact):

```
class Complex(object):

    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 0):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def __str__(self):
        if self._a == 0 and self._b == 0:
            return "0"
        else:
            return "(" + str(self._a) + " , " + str(self._b) + "i)"

    def __add__(self, other):
        res = Complex(
            self._a + other._a,
            self._b + other._b)

        return (str(self) + " + " + str(other) + " = " + str(res))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        res = Complex(
            self._a - other._a,
            self._b - other._b)

        return (str(self) + " - " + str(other) + " = " + str(res))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        res = Complex(
            self._a * other._a - self._b * other._b,
            self._a * other._b + self._b * other._a)

        return (str(self) + " * " + str(other) + " = " + str(res))

    def __div__(self, other):

        norm = other._a ** 2 + other._b ** 2
        res = Complex(
            (self._a * other._a + self._b * other._b) / norm,
            (-self._a * other._b + self._b * other._a) / norm)

        return (str(self) + " / " + str(other) + " = " + str(res))


def main():
    c1 = raw_input("Enter the first complex number: ")
    re, im = c1.split()
    c1 = Complex(a=float(re), b=float(im))
    # or:
    # re_im = c1.split()
    # c1 = Complex(a=float(re_im[0]), b=float(re_im[1]))

    c2 = raw_input("Enter the second complex number: ")
    re, im = c2.split()
    c2 = Complex(a=float(re), b=float(im))
    print c1
    print c2
    print c1 + c2
    print c1 - c2
    print c1 * c2
    print c1 / c2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```